# Nhibernate GetById returns ObjectNotFoundException insetad of null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent Nhibernate. This code Loads an instance of type T from the DB based on its ID.

```
public T GetById(IdT id, bool shouldLock)
    {
        T entity;

        if (shouldLock)
        {
            entity = (T) NHibernateSession.Load(persitentType, id, LockMode.Upgrade);
        }
        else
        {
            entity = (T) NHibernateSession.Load(persitentType, id);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

But I have big problem. When I call property on it I get `ObjectNotFoundException` instead of `null`.

How can I make that entity be nullable and not return the Exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use Get instead of Load.  Get will return null, instead of an exception.

Comment: -1. Entity type is nullable, it is most likely a reference type.

Comment: Regardless, the solution to the problem is to use Get, rather than trying to lazy load...

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer just lacking the explanation I gave with mine.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're mistaken in what `Load` does. This create an NHibernate proxy object for you by ID without actually querying the database.

When you invoke a property it will query the database, if you supplied a bad id there is no underlying object hence the exception.

The normal situtations you will use this is for is say you have a State object and the user selected PA in a drop down. Instead of having to query the database for the State object since you already have the key PA you can call `Load` and then pass that state object into a different object to have the correct relationship of Object X to State PA.

The method you want to be using for general get object or get null if key does not exist is just `Session.Get<T>(object ID)`

Answer (score 4):

`Load` will never return null. It will always return an entity or throw an exception. If you want that behaviour use `Get`. More info on this [Difference between Get and Load](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx)